# Oracle string aggregation in group by

Tags: oracle

I have formed a large query which fetches a large data set with the below data condition.

```
Column1 Column2  
M1        OTH  
M1        HHM  
M1        RES  
M2        HHM  
M2        RES  
M3        OTH  
M3        RES
```

I need to form it as:

```
M1        OTH,HHM,RES  
M2        HHM,RES  
M3        OTH,RES
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the available string aggregation techniques described in [this document](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php).

For instance:

```
SELECT COLUMN1, LISTAGG(COLUMN2, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN1) AS COLUMN2s
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN1;
```